# git ignore all files except one extension and folder structure

Tags: git, gitignore

What I want is to ignore all kind of files except the .php ones, but with this .gitignore I'm also ignoring folders...

```
#ignore all kind of files
*
#except php files
!*.php
```

Is there a way to tell git to accept my project folder structure while keeping the track only of the .php files?

It seems like now I can't add folders to my repo:

```
vivo@vivoPC:~/workspace/motor$ git add my_folder/
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
my_folder
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Comment: git only tracks files not directories.  If you ignore all the file in the directory it won't be added to the project.

Comment: I've edited my question, seems like now I can't add that folder.

Comment: What is in the directory?

Comment: loots of files of diferent types (.php, .sql, other subfolders...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is simple, just add another entry `!my_folder` in your `.gitignore`

```
#ignore all kind of files
*
#except php files
!*.php
!my_folder
```

The last line will take special care of `my_folder`, and will not ignore any php files within it; but files within other folders will still be ignored because of the first pattern of `*`.

**EDIT**

I think I misread your question. If you want to ignore all files except `.php` files, you can use

```
#ignore all kind of files
*.*
#except php files
!*.php
```

This will not ignore any file which doesn't have an extension (example: if you have `README` and not `README.txt` ), and will ignore any folder with a `.` in its name (example: directory named `module.1`).

FWIW, [git doesn't track directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18592006/1860929), and hence there is no way to specify ignore rules for directory vs file

Comment: thanks, it works. But could it be possible to not ignore any folder even if we don't specify it in .gitignore?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, as far as I understand now, gitignore rules doesn't difference between folders and files. If we had a way to tell "this rule is for files" or "this rule is for dirs" ..

Comment: @vivoconunxino no thats not possible; git doesn't track folders at all. The entries in gitignore are patterns, and any filename or filepath(means directory) matching it is ignored.

Comment: Is there some way to write the exception before the ignore statement and still make it function properly?

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem; I wanted to whitelist `*.c`, but the accepted answer didn't work for me,  because I had files that didn't contain ".".

So for those who want to handle that:

```
# ignore everything
*

# but don't ignore files ending with slash = directories
!*/

# and don't ignore files ending with ".php"
!*.php
```

Comment: perfect! (add `!.gitignore`)

Answer (score 17):

This works for me (excludes all imgs folder content except .gitkeep files)

```
/imgs/**/*.*
!/imgs/**/.gitkeep
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. (I didn't need the beginning slash)

Comment: Note that this won't work if there are `.` characters in your directory names. You'll have to insert the following between your two lines `!/imgs/**/*.*/`

Answer (score 6):

Note that if the `!` has no effect, you probably excluded a folder. From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) (emphasis mine):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
> excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not
> possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is
> excluded**. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance
> reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter
> where they are defined.

Comment: Important hint, many thanks.

Comment: To work around this limitation you can re-add all of the directory entries. Ex: `mydir/** ; ~mydir/**/ ; !mydir/**/*.myextension`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the one that I was looking for, so adding the one that worked for me.

The following declaration states that,

1. ignore everything (including subdirs recursively)
2. Exclude specific files from being ignored
3. Exclude all subdirs from being ignored

Now if you note `step-3`, you can see that it `has cumulative effect of step-1, 2 declarations`. ie, **when unignoring each subdir recursively, ignore everything directly under that subdir except few files ignored in step-2**. This will be `carried out for each subdir that is being processed`, hence the order/sequence of declaration is important.

Example:

```
subdir1
  \subdir11\others.txt
  \subdir12\build.xml
  .gitignore
subdir2
  \subdir21\resources\build.xml
  \subdir22\build.xml
build.xml
.gitignore
```

`.gitignore` file should contain

```
# !! NOTE: the sequence of declaration is important !!

# Ignore Everything
*

# Exclude specific files from being ignored (override)
!.gitignore
!*.xml

# overrides stated above, applies to all dir (root and subdirs - recursively)
!**/
```

Results:

```
subdir1\subdir12\build.xml
subdir1\.gitignore
subdir2\subdir21\resources\build.xml
subdir2\subdir22\build.xml
build.xml
.gitignore
```

After this `if you still want to trim down or filter more` out of the ones you have filtered already, `add it next to the processing` **(remember: Sequence is important)**

```
# !! NOTE: the sequence of declaration is important !!

# Ignore Everything
*

# Exclude specific files from being ignored (override)
!.gitignore
!build.xml

# overrides stated above, applies to all dir (root and subdirs - recursively)
!**/

**/resources/**
```

Now This will add step-4 which is to **ignore *.xml** (in subdirs only) **whose subdir path contains intermediate `resources` dir, that were filtered as results till step-3**.

Results:

```
subdir1\subdir12\build.xml
subdir1\.gitignore
subdir2\subdir22\build.xml
build.xml
.gitignore
```

This doesn't stop here, `you can also ignore unignored files in step-2 only for subdirs` (So that they are included only for rootdir but not in subdirs)

```
# !! NOTE: the sequence of declaration is important !!

# Ignore Everything
*

# Exclude specific files from being ignored (override)
!.gitignore
!build.xml

# overrides stated above, applies to all dir (root and subdirs - recursively)
!**/
**/resources
**/.gitignore
```

In addition to step-4 results this will exclude `.gitignore` in all subdirs except for root dir.

Answer (score 0):

You need re-include every dir in path to your file:

```
# ignore all kind of files
*
# except all dirs on the way
!**/
# except php files
!*.php
```

If you have different files split between different dirs:

```
*

# except php dir
!/php/
# except every directory in php
!/php/**/
# except every php file in php dir
!/php/**/*.php

# and same for css
!/css/
!/css/**/
!/css/**/*.css
```