# gitignore all files except the .json files in all subdirectories of a particular directory

Tags: git, gitignore

my current directory tree looks like:

```
.
├── test1
│   ├── test.docx
│   ├── test.jpg
│   ├── test.json
│   ├── test2
│   │   ├── test.docx
│   │   ├── test.jpg
│   │   ├── test.json
│   │   └── test4
│   │       ├── test.docx
│   │       ├── test.jpg
│   │       └── test.json
│   └── test3
│       ├── test.docx
│       ├── test.jpg
│       └── test.json
└── test5
    ├── test.docx
    ├── test.jpg
    ├── test.json
    ├── test2
    │   ├── test.docx
    │   ├── test.jpg
    │   ├── test.json
    │   └── test4
    │       ├── test.docx
    │       ├── test.jpg
    │       └── test.json
    └── test3
        ├── test.docx
        ├── test.jpg
        └── test.json
```

I want to ignore everything except `.json` files which are under `test1` directory.

my `.gitignore` file looks like:

```
/*
!/.gitignore
!/test1
/test1/**/*.json
```

my `git status -sb` output is:

```
## No commits yet on master
?? .gitignore
```

So, it is not tracking the `.json` files under `test1` directory.

What might be the solution here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your `.gitignore` file:

```
# ignore all files
**/*.*

# except json files in test1 folder
!test1/**/*.json
```

There is also a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677866/git-ignore-all-files-except-one-extension-and-folder-structure) where you can find the basic for the solution.

Comment: it worked after I replaced `*.*` with `**/*.*`. I am accepting the answer but please make the amendment.

Answer (score 0):

Try only this line in .gitignore file

test1/!*.json