# gitignore pattern to include all files of type and directories that contain them

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

Me and a partner are working on a Unity project with a lot of scripts buried within many folders and subdirectories. It is difficult to keep track of where these scripts are located specifically, so I wondered if there is a way to have git include all files with the .cs extension and the directories containing them, while ignoring everything else.

Would something like **/*.cs suffice?

Comment: Why would you ignore everything else? To fully back-up and restore a Unity project you need a lot more than just the scripts. Use [`this gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) in your project. It should ignore everything you do not need while retaining everything you do.

Comment: If you still would like to just ignore all files except for .cs files, you can use [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677866/git-ignore-all-files-except-one-extension-and-folder-structure)

Comment: We are not trying to backup the entire project, we just want to share scripts and certain files

Comment: Gotcha, then the answer I linked in my second comment should ignore all files except for all ending in `.cs`. Just swap the `.php` for `.cs`. I don't believe there is a way to ignore the directories files are in as that breaks the relative file structure. Best you can do is just ignore all the other files. The other options is to just back them up manually to some cloud service.

Comment: You might want to read also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267842/cleaning-up-and-migrating-existing-unity-project-into-new-one-or-another-pc) why what you are asking for is a really really bad idea! As already mentioned by others Unity requires a lot more files then just your `.cs` scripts! Which in short means -> Use the official `.gitignore` linked by @TEEBQNE!

Comment: @TEEBQNE actually the second answer of your other link is only semi-correct ([phd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246308/7111561) answer here has it correct) `!*/` only keeps first level folders .. you would want `!**/` where `**` is a path wildcard

Answer (score 0):

> Would something like **/*.cs suffice?

It would suffice for the task "ignore all files with `.cs` extension". Actually for such a task a simpler pattern `*.cs` would suffice.

Unfortunately, you want to solve a reverse task — "ignore everything **except** files with `.cs` extension". This is a harder task because when you start with "ignore everything" Git ignores all files in subdirectories. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format); the most relevant part is

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn't list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

So after ignoring everything you need to "unignore" (re-include) directories and then include `*.cs`. This is your `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore everything everywhere
*
# Unignore directories and subdirectories recursively
!/**/
# Include *.cs
!*.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard gitignore from github for Unity projects (its not perfect its a bit out of date but its fine)

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

I recommend using this.. If you *only* use version control on .cs files that could result in some weird stuff, Unity saves crucial data in other files, like project settings, meta files, scene files, prefab files etc.

Eg. If person A's scene is missing something that person B added, then how will person A know the script they are working on is actually working?