# Git: Ignore Subfolder of All Folders Except One

Tags: git, gitignore

currenty I have an repository that looks like this:

```
Git-Repository
└─── A
│  └─── X
│  └─── Y
└─── B
│  └─── X
│  └─── Y
└─── C
│  └─── X
│  └─── Y
│ ....
```

I want to edit my *.gitignore* file to somehow **ignore all X subdirectories except the one in C directory.**

It is important to mention that this is a simple version of my real repo. I actually have a LOT more folders and subfolders, so I cant set all the directories one by one.

Edit1:
This is what I am trying to do, but not working.
X subdirectory is being correcyly ignored, but the one in "C" isnt ""unignored""

```
X/
!C/X/*
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git ignore all files except one extension and folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677866/git-ignore-all-files-except-one-extension-and-folder-structure)

Comment: @Schwern I have tried it but it is not working

Comment: @Miguel Have any files in those directories already been committed?

Comment: @Schwern not yet. Still trying to make the "unignore" part to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself.

That means `X/` will only match a top level `X` directory.

To match subdirectories, use a wildcard.

```
*/X/
!C/X/
```

Comment: Still not working properly... "X" was beeing ignored in both ways, but the on in "C" directory isnt being """unignored"""

Comment: @Miguel Works For Me™. We'd need more information.

Comment: Just realized that I was addind an extra star (*) at the end of the "unignore" command.  Removing it solve the problem