# gitignore - how do I ignore all files, except files with certain extension, anywhere in the repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

What should I put in `.gitignore` so that git ignores everything except JSON files (with file extension .json) anywhere in the repo (could be deep inside of some dir)?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not .json files (including those in subdirectories)
!/**/*.json
```

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for the link. I've tried both `!/**/*.json` and `!**/*.json` as suggested in that answer, but neither worked.

Comment: Unignore all directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606028/7976758

Comment: @TeddyC I have personally tested with `*.* \ !*.json`

Comment: I tried `*.*\n!*.json`, I wasn't sure if all jsons are tracked, but I found that some non-json files are tracked.